# Can't see any fields for user name or password when logging in

Tags: support, login, stackexchange.com

I opened http://stackexchange.com website and clicked the login link at the top, and this is what I see:

> [image]

I don't see any place where I can fill my email address and password in order to log in and change my name.

Comment: What URL did you go to and which client software (browser, iOS, Android, etc) were you using? Can you provide a screenshot of how the login page appears to you?

Comment: @Adam I have clarified the question, can you please reopen? The main issue here, is that the login on the stackexchange.com portal is now different than the login on all other sites, where it's showing the textboxes for SE OpenID by default, so I agree it's confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Click "log in with Stack Exchange" and the email/password form will load.

However, if all you're trying to do is change your display name, you should do that from a Q&A site instead. User profiles on stackexchange.com are basically read-only.

To edit your profile (you can do this here on MSE), click your avatar in the topbar and go to the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab.

Comment: Will stackexchange.com take the latest display name after editing in a site, or should the user manually do it, after the recent change?

Comment: @ShadowWizard If they have a user on stackexchange.com, yes. Otherwise, no. (It's ... not obvious whether one does or not. Need to fix that one of these days.)

Comment: Thanks, worth adding this to  the answer then. :-)